# Expected value of next CPU burst using exponential averaging

Tags: operating-systems, process-scheduling

The burst time is needed for Shortest Job First (SJF) and Shortest Run Time First (SRTF) scheduling. To get the approximate burst time, we use the equation
$$\tau_{n + 1} = t_n + (1 - \alpha)\tau_n$$

I want to ask whether $\tau_{n + 1}$ is the predicted burst time of the $n + 1$ th process or it is the predicted burst time of some process say p which is demanding the CPU for the $n + 1$ th time.

Comment: Given that you have observed $n$ processes so far, $\tau_{n+1}$ is the $n+1^{th}$ process's expected burst time.

Comment: @RandomPerfectHashFunction I doubt it. What benefit does predicting the burst time of $n + 1^{th}$ process gives us?

Comment: But if we can predict the next burst time of every process which we have encountered so for, we can schedule the one with smallest predicted burst time.

Comment: I think this answer explains it better [link](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/51553).